# Telling Haskell compiler that two types are compatible

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I've got the following Haskell function:

```
apply_to_f :: (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> b) -> ((b -> c) -> c)
apply_to_f f = \ g -> \ h -> h (g f)
```

(This comes from the 'pred' function for Church numerals).

There's a constraint that I want to tell the compiler about: it is possible to compose `(apply_to_f f)` with itself.

In other words, `(apply_to_f f)` takes a function of type `(a -> a) -> a` and it also returns a function of type `(a -> a) -> a`.

So is it possible to tell the compiler that it needs to unify the types `(a -> a) -> b` and `(b -> c) -> c` in the type of `apply_to_f`, or do I have to figure that out myself if I want to write down the precise type of the function?

My initial guess was that I might be able to write a vague type for `apply_to_f`, using a type variable to indicate this constraint. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why do you want the less general (more restricted) type? As it is right now, `apply_to_f f . apply_to_f f` compiles, and has type `apply_to_f id . apply_to_f id :: ((a -> a) -> b) -> (b -> c) -> c`. There are ways to restrict the type, like unifying the variables yourself, or adding something like `(T ~ U) => ...`, but I wonder what's the rationale.

Comment: It seemed like there should be a way to express the stated constraint (and there is!) instead of writing the restricted type myself. In the context of Church numerals, the restricted type is a key to (understanding) the way the ```pred``` function works—see varous explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790249/lambda-calculus-predecessor-function-reduction-steps

Comment: You might also like [Unifying c -> a -> b and (a -> b) -> c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32368507/791604).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities.  First, you can express the extra constraint as a type equality:

```
apply_to_f :: ((a -> a) -> b) ~ ((b -> c) -> c)
  => (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> b) -> ((b -> c) -> c)
```

Note that the resulting type signature is *not* precisely equivalent to:

```
apply_to_f :: (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> a)
```

In particular, GHCi will report different types for these two type signatures, and the error reported if `apply_to_f` is used at the "wrong type" will be different.  For example, the following code type checks:

```
apply_to_f :: (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> b) -> ((b -> c) -> c)
apply_to_f f = \ g -> \ h -> h (g f)

foo = apply_to_f id id
```

If you restrict the type of `apply_to_f` with a direct type signature:

```
apply_to_f :: (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> a)
```

the resulting type error will be associated with the second `id` in the definition of `foo` and will be accompanied by a clear explanation of the expected version actual types for this second `id`:

```
Unify.hs:13:21-22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a -> a’
      Expected: (a -> a) -> a
        Actual: (a -> a) -> a -> a
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the inferred type of foo :: (a -> a) -> a
        at Unify.hs:13:1-22
    • In the second argument of ‘apply_to_f’, namely ‘id’
      In the expression: apply_to_f id id
      In an equation for ‘foo’: foo = apply_to_f id id
    • Relevant bindings include
        foo :: (a -> a) -> a (bound at Unify.hs:13:1)
   |
13 | foo = apply_to_f id id
   |                     ^^
```

while if you use a constraint instead:

```
apply_to_f :: ((a -> a) -> b) ~ ((b -> c) -> c)
  => (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> b) -> ((b -> c) -> c)
```

then the type error will be associated with the use of `apply_to_f` in the definition of `foo` and will be more vaguely associated with "some problem in foo's inferred type":

```
Unify.hs:12:7-16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a -> a’
        arising from a use of ‘apply_to_f’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the inferred type of foo :: ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> a -> a
        at Unify.hs:12:1-22
    • In the expression: apply_to_f id id
      In an equation for ‘foo’: foo = apply_to_f id id
    • Relevant bindings include
        foo :: ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> a -> a (bound at Unify.hs:12:1)
   |
12 | foo = apply_to_f id id
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Nonetheless, I think the differences between these two signatures are probably cosmetic in most cases, and they should behave about the same for practical purposes.

Second, you can leverage the type checker to calculate the desired type for `apply_to_f` by forcing the type checker to type check expressions that require the constraint.  For example, the definition:

```
apply_to_f = general_apply_to_f
  where general_apply_to_f :: (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> b) -> ((b -> c) -> c)
        general_apply_to_f f = \ g -> \ h -> h (g f)

        _ = apply_to_f undefined . apply_to_f undefined
```

will result in the type of `apply_to_f` being correctly inferred as:

```
λ> :t apply_to_f
apply_to_f :: (a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a
```